# How to "add" user-defined format flags to basic_ostream?

Tags: c++

I want to provide a stream operator to output `std::chrono::time_point` as GMT date, I currently have the following (simplified for `ostream` only):

```
using datetime_t = std::chrono::system_clock::time_point;

std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream &out, datetime_t dt) {
    auto time = datetime_t::clock::to_time_t(dt);
    auto under_sec = 
        std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::milliseconds>(
            dt.time_since_epoch() % std::chrono::seconds{1});
    return out << std::put_time(std::gmtime(&time), "%Y-%m-%dT:%H:%M:%S")
               << "." << std::setfill('0') << std::setw(3) << under_sec.count();
}
```

Usage:

```
auto time = datetime_t::clock::now();
std::cout << time;
```

This works, but it forces the user to:

- use the hard-coded format;
- output milliseconds.

I would like to provide custom stream manipulator that would allow the user to modify both of these, e.g. for the second (assuming a namespace `nm` containing the manipulator):

```
std::cout << nm::us << time;
```

...that would print up to microseconds.

I already know how to create stream manipulators, e.g.:

```
namespace nm {
    std::ios_base& us(std::ios_base &) { /* ... */ }
}
```

...but I don't know how to "store" the required information for use in the  output operator.

Is there a simply way to "store" information in a stream (user-defined format flags?) to use in a later stream operation? Or another way to obtain slightly equivalent behavior?

Comment: In this case you might want a "manipulator" that takes the time as an argument.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude This would be an option, but I'd rather not have to write `std::cout << nm::us(time);` (if this what you meant, otherwise I do not know what you are talking about ;)).

Comment: Yes that's what I meant. And that is what e.g. `put_time` does, and any other manipulator that doesn't modify the stream object. And no there's no way to add custom or user-data to the (standard) stream object.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude These manipulator would actually modify the stream, like `std::setw` or `std::setfill` since `std::cout << nm::us << time1 << " " << time2` would output microseconds for both times.

Comment: Yes I understand, but e.g. the `setw` manipulator calls public functions in the stream object (in the case of `setw` it calls [`ios_base::width`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/ios_base/width)). There are simply no way to store special or user-defined data like your time-format in the stream object.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Actually [there is](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/ios_base/iword), like always I found them after posting my question...

Comment: Hot damn, forgot about those! Yes if your data can be stored in  a `long` then `iword` is perfect, otherwise allocate some data and use `pword` instead. The problem then is how will the manipulator and the `operator<<` function know which index to use? It has to be a unique one that no one else could use.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude How about a global atomic variable which is 0 if not (yet) assigned. The first output operator or manipulator which tries to use it may initiate the assignment with [`std::ios_base::xalloc()`](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Home_Theater_Personal_Computer). The global atomic might be "hidden" in a respective access function.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I found implementations initialising the index via a static variables in a wrapping function using xalloc - All access to the data go through this function, so the index is consistent everywhere.

Answer (score 2):

As you've already discovered in your comments, yes, streams have, `iword` and `pword` storage.  Not the easiest thing in the world to work with (designed decades ok), but serviceable.

Another option would be to use an already coded library for this such as [Howard Hinnant's free, open source, datetime library](https://howardhinnant.github.io/date/date.html):

```
#include "date.h"
#include <iostream>

int
main()
{  
    using namespace date;
    using namespace std::chrono;
    std::cout << format("%FT:%T", floor<microseconds>(system_clock::now())) << '\n';
}
```

With this library the precision of the output is controlled by adjusting the precision of the input (i.e. with `time_point_cast` or `floor`).

Sample output:

```
2017-07-10T:11:46:59.354321
```

Comment: Thanks, I already knew about your (awesome) datetime library but I wanted a more generic way - I provided an example for datetime but I actually want to use this for some other types too (representing various units).